# Custom DataAnnotation in asp.net mvc not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
[Required]
[ValidatePasswordLength]

[DataType(DataType.Password)] 
[Display(Name = "Password")]
[Minimumthreenumbers]
public string Password { get; set; }

public class MinimumthreenumbersAttribute : ValidationAttribute 
{

    private const string _defaultErrorMessage = "There should be minimum three letters in the string";

    private string Otherpassword;

    public MinimumthreenumbersAttribute() : base(_defaultErrorMessage)
    {


    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string i = value.ToString();
        string jobId = i;
        int digitsCount = 0;
        foreach (char c in jobId)
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(c))
                digitsCount++;
        }

        if (digitsCount > 3)
        {

            return true;
        }


        else
        {

            return false;
        }


    }
}
```

The above is the custom attribute implementation class .`The above code actually has to validate the password to check for minimum 3 numbers.If the user entered password has less than 3 digits it should throw an error`.This is the requirement. But is not working as expected. Any ideas on how to make the above code working? I have tried for some time but still it is not working.

Comment: How is it not working? You have to tell us what it's doing and what you expect it to do. We're not mind readers.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that will be enough to make your code "work", but at least this will simplify your code.

```
public class MinimumthreenumbersAttribute : ValidationAttribute 
{
   public MinimumthreenumbersAttribute() : base("There should be minimum three letters in the string")
   {
   }

   public override bool IsValid(object value)
   {
       return value != null && 
              value.ToString()
                   .Where(Char.IsDigit)
                   .Count() >=3
   }
}
```

Comment: Raphal it is still not working as expected . The password should have atleaset three didgits . I was wondering is there any mandatory need to implement the IClientValidatable interface ?

Comment: @user2465036 be more precise that "not working as expected". What do you really expect which is not happening ?

Comment: The  code actually has to validate the password to check for minimum 3 numbers.If the user entered a password which is less than 3 digits it should throw an error.This is the requirement

Comment: Currently even though i enter 2 numbers ,it is accepting and not throwing an error. The requirement is it is not supposed to allow a password in which there are less than 3 numbers

Comment: Server side ..public class MinimumthreenumbersAttribute : ValidationAttribute 
{
   public MinimumthreenumbersAttribute() : base("There should be minimum three letters in the string")
   {
   }

   public override bool IsValid(object value)
   {
       return value != null && 
              value.ToString()
                   .Where(Char.IsDigit)
                   .Count() >=3
   }
}

Comment: And on the property, you don't put `[MinimumthreenumbersAttribute()]` but `[Minimumthreenumbers]` right ?

Comment: Yea ..The propery goes this way

Comment: [Required]
        [ValidatePasswordLength]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
      
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [Minimumthreenumbers]
        public string Password { get; set; }

Comment: and in your post action, `ModelState.IsValid` is true if you put only two digits ?

Comment: Yes Raphel .It is true.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a RegularExpressionAttribute to ensure there are three digits:

```
[RegularExpression(@".*\d.*\d.*\d.*")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: Rubie. Thanks for the solution the password is validatin ,but i am interested in that custom validation . I want to learn about how to overide the base class methods and whats going on the custom validation